# adding menu to a curses python program

Tags: python

I am writing a text UI program using python and curses and am trying to add menus to the display but I cant find any documentation on adding menus for curses in python.Any pointers to how this can be done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python library for curses [does not seem to support](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/curses.html#for-more-information) the menu extensions available for n-curses. However, if you can using Python2 (most likely), you can try [patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue1723038) available here.